# need to reduce an expression in wxmaxima with complex numbers and units

Tags: maxima, wxmaxima

I have this expression in WXMAXIMA:

`100/(25.00079433726757*%i+20)`

How can i reduce to the form  a + %i b?

I tried rectform, float, polarform... Any of those functions seem to simplify that simple calculus. Just two numbers. Dont imagine how...

Full process:

```
(%i2)   load("ezunits");
numer: true;
(%o1)   "/usr/share/maxima/5.45.1/share/ezunits/ezunits.mac"
(%o2)   true

(%i3)   R1: 20`ohm;
(%o3)   20 ` ohm

(%i9)   f:50`Hz;  w: 2*%pi*f;
        L1: 79.58 `mH;
        Z1: R1 + (w*L1 ``ohm) * %i;
        cabs(Z1); float(carg(Z1)) `` degree;
(%o4)   50 ` Hz
(%o5)   314.1592653589793 ` Hz
(%o6)   79.58 ` mH
(%o7)   (25.00079433726757*%i+20) ` ohm
(%o8)   32.01624146420611 ` ohm^1.0
(%o9)   51.34107977110403 ` degree



(%i81)  V: 100 ` volt;
        I1: V / Z1;
        rectform(I1);

(%o79)  100 ` volt

(%o80)  100/(25.00079433726757*%i+20) ` volt/ohm
(%o81)  realpart(100/(25.00079433726757*%i+20) `     volt/ohm)+%i*imagpart(100/(25.00079433726757*%i+20) ` volt/ohm)
```

As u can see at %o81, the calculus isn't simplified.  Maybe unit affected? Tried to remove unit with nounit() but still everything is not simplified

```
(%i84)  V: 100 ` volt;
        I1: V / Z1;
        nounit(rectform(I1));

(%o82)  100 ` volt

(%o83)  100/(25.00079433726757*%i+20) ` volt/ohm
(%o84)  nounit(realpart(100/(25.00079433726757*%i+20) ` volt/ohm)+%i*imagpart(100/(25.00079433726757*%i+20) ` volt/ohm))
```

Comment: Hmm, with `rectform`, I get `1.9511439077588948 - 2.4390073780146353 %i` -- is that what you're looking for? What do you get with `rectform`?

Comment: I extended my main statement. As you cn see, results dont simplify.

Comment: Oh, okay, I see you are using units. Let me figure out what to do, it will take just a few minutes.

Comment: I put an answer below, hope that helps. Another minor comment: to get just the quantity part of a dimensional expression, you can say: ``qty(a ` b)`` and it returns just `a`. Likewise ``units(a ` b)`` returns `b`.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here's what I figured out that works. I'll start with the definitions you made.

```
(%i2) load ("ezunits");
(%o2) /home/robert/tmp/maxima-read-only-git/maxima-code/share/ez\
units/ezunits.mac
(%i3) R1: 20`ohm;
(%o3)                       20 ` ohm
(%i4) f:50`Hz;
(%o4)                        50 ` Hz
(%i5) w: 2*%pi*f;
(%o5)                     100 %pi ` Hz
(%i6) L1: 79.58 `mH;
(%o6)                      79.58 ` mH
(%i7) Z1: R1 + (w*L1 ``ohm) * %i;
(%o7)               (7.958 %i %pi + 20) ` ohm
(%i8) V: 100 ` volt;
(%o8)                      100 ` volt
(%i9) I1: V / Z1;
                           100          volt
(%o9)               ----------------- ` ----
                    7.958 %i %pi + 20   ohm
(%i10) rectform(I1);
                       100          volt
(%o10) realpart(----------------- ` ----)
                7.958 %i %pi + 20   ohm
                                               100          volt
                          + %i imagpart(----------------- ` ----)
                                        7.958 %i %pi + 20   ohm
```

Okay, now %o10 is the same result you got before. The ezunits package has some rules for handling `realpart` and `imagpart`, but they weren't fully applied yet; that's probably a bug. To cause the units to move from inside `realpart` and `imagpart`, we can cause the expression to be resimplified by re-evaluating it via `''%` as in %i11.

```
(%i11) ''%;
                        100
(%o11) (realpart(-----------------)
                 7.958 %i %pi + 20
                                              100            volt
                         + %i imagpart(-----------------)) ` ----
                                       7.958 %i %pi + 20     ohm
```

Now `realpart` and `imagpart` only contain numerical expressions; `volt/ohm` was moved outside. Now to cause `realpart` and `imagpart` to evaluate the numerical expressions, we can "verbify" `realpart` and `imagpart` via `ev(...)` as in %i12.

```
(%i12) ev (%, realpart, imagpart);
                2000           795.8000000000001 %i %pi    volt
(%o12) (-------------------- - ------------------------) ` ----
                     2                        2            ohm
        63.329764 %pi  + 400     63.329764 %pi  + 400
```

Now %o12 is just a numerical expression, and we can apply `float`.

```
(%i13) float (%);
                                                     volt
(%o13)  (1.951143907758894 - 2.439007378014635 %i) ` ----
                                                     ohm
```

So the key points were %i11 and %i12. I'm sorry that these operations are completely unintuitive; the problem you ran into is a consequence of subtle and obscure aspects of Maxima. I hope that these notes help you make progress all the same. Thanks for your interest in Maxima, and ezunits in particular (I wrote the package).

EDIT: Another thing to try when working with units. There is a function `dimensionally` (undocumented, sorry about that) which helps other functions, which are not aware of units, to handle the units. In this case it can help `rectform`. With `I1` as before, I get

```
(%i4) dimensionally (rectform (I1));
                   2000
(%o4) (-----------------------------
                             2
       63.329764000000004 %pi  + 400
                              795.8000000000001 %i %pi       volt
                          - -----------------------------) ` ----
                                                  2          ohm
                            63.329764000000004 %pi  + 400
```

which is the same result as before, but a little bit sooner to get there.